# Electron : buttons randomly resize the window

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, electron, draggable

I am developping my first app using Electron and I have a little but annoying bug.
I decided to display my app as a frameless window, and to set the header of my HTML as a draggable area to be able to move the window. I also added three buttons to resize, minimize and close my app. Everything is fine and it looks good.

The problem is that sometimes, randomly, one of the buttons displayed on my interface doesn't responds to click. The only way to reactivate it is to double click on it.. And it resizes the window (if it is already fullscreen it unmaximizes it and vice versa).

I tried to google this issue, but I found nothing. The only thing that I found was to set the draggable property of my buttons to true or false, but the bug is still there :(

As my code is VERY long, I have no idea what to share with you. It really appears anywhere and anytime, and it's annoying.

UPDATE : it appears that there is another was to reactivate the buttons : scrolling. Some buttons, when displayed on specific areas, are bugged. When I scroll them away from this area, everything is fine. And the other buttons don't have a problem with the area. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Post a snippet of the the way you're creating the BrowserWindow & the HTML part for the buttons.